# Submit color spectrum data to PHP back end using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, spectrumjs

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Pick color
2. Display value
3. Display color in `div`
4. On `submit`, post AJAX to PHP

I feel like I am very close, just need that extra push as to where I am going wrong.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZoesch/pnyhotnu/).

My current JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.targetColor = '#ec9040';
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

jQuery(function () {
    var field1 = $('#field1');

    $('#send').click(
        function () {
            console.log('fieldvalue: field1.val()')
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "colormystatus.php",
                data: {
                    field1value: field1.val()
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `jQuery(function () {})` into your controller, and send `$scope.targetColor` instead of `field1.val()`: ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnyhotnu/2/))

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.targetColor = '#ec9040';

    jQuery(function () {
        $('#send').click(function () {
            console.log('$scope.targetColor:', $scope.targetColor)
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
                data: {
                        field1value: $scope.targetColor
                       },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                                        alert(data);
                                         }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think,for your post processing use app.factory.The returned data use in controller .So jQuery(function () will be unnecessary.Review following code sample.

```
 app.factory('ColorFactory'),['$http',
        function ($http) {
            var colorFactory={};
            colorFactory.targetPostColor=function(field1){
                return $http({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "colormystatus.php",
                            data: {
                                    field1value: field1.val()
                                   }
                    })
            }
            return colorFactory;
        }];

        app.controller('MyCtrl',['ColorFactory','$scope',
            function($scope,ColorFactory)
            $scope.targetColor = '#ec9040';
            ColorFactory.targetPostColor($scope.targetColor).success(function(data) { 
                         coonsole.log(data);
            })
           }
        ]);
```